# WCF Service doesn't check client certificate CRL chain

Tags: c#, wcf, security, certificate

Endpoint Binding is WSHttpBinding with security mode=Message, and clientCredentialType=Certificate.

I set the following behavior on the server side(Set server certificate and validate client certificate):

```
<behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
<serviceCredentials>
     <serviceCertificate 
          storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
          storeName="My" 
          x509FindType="SubjectName"    
          findValue="CN=MyServerCertificateName" />
     <clientCertificate>
          <authentication 
           certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" 
           trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" 
           revocationMode="Online" />
      </clientCertificate>
</serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
```

I Set the client the certificate in the following way:

```
 <behavior name="clientEndpointCredential">
     <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate 
              storeName="My" 
              storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
              findValue="MyClientCertificateName" />
      </clientCredentials>
  </behavior>
```

With this code the server checks the client CRL and peer trust. This check works fine.

The Problem is when i add the following code in the client credentials:

```
           <serviceCertificate>
               <authentication 
                   certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" 
                   trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" 
                   revocationMode="Online" />
           </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
```

When i change the clientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication Properties the CRL chain is not checked! The crl publish server is down and the server still receive the client messages!

I wanted to add this code in order to make the client verify the chain of server certificate.

Thank you for your help in advance.